# Waiting for an asynchronous response?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, client

I am designing a multiclient/server software in c#. Right now, I am using it as asynchronous.

In some cases, I want client side to wait for the answer.

For example, I need to send server a command to fetch me some info from the database and client program should continue according to the fetched data. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could wait on the [`IAsyncResult.WaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.asyncwaithandle%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), if this interface is being used in your scenario.